# Urn balls multinomial with joint probability function

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $w$ white, $b$ black and $r$ red balls. $n$ extractions with replacement are made. $X_w$, $X_b$ and $X_r$ are the random variables representing the number of white, black and red balls extracted. I should find:

1. domain and probability function for marginal $X_i$, where $i$ is $w$ or $b$ or $r$
2. domain and joint probability function for random vector $(X_w, X_b, X_r)$
3. $P(a<X_i<b)$

**Question 1**

I set $t = w+b+r$ as the sum of the balls inside the urn, so for each colors the probability is $p_w=\frac{w}{w+b+r}$, $p_b=\frac{b}{w+b+r}$ and $p_r=\frac{r}{w+b+r}$

Now the marginal for $X_i$ should be $P(X_i=e)=\binom{n}{e}p_i^e(1-p_i)^{n-e}$ with domain for $X_i$ ${0}\le{e}\le{i}$

**Question 2**

The domain is the set of 3-tuple $(n_w,n_b,n_r)$ where $n_w + n_b + n_r = n$ and joint probability function is 
$P(X_w=n_w, X_b=n_b, X_r=n_r) = \frac{n!}{{n_w!}{n_b!}{n_r!}}{p_w}^{n_w}{p_b}^{n_b}{p_r}^{n_r}$

**Question 3**

$P(a<X_i<b) = \sum_{k=a-1}^{b-1}\dbinom{n}{k}{p_i}^k(1-p_i)^{n-k}$

Is everything correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is mostly correct.

In Question $3$, since the inequalities on the left are strict, the bounds shouldn't be included in the summation on the right.

In Question $1$, your dual use of $i$ as an index and as the corresponding variable is slightly unorthodox, but clear enough upon reflection.

Comment: Thanks, I've made my correction. What do you suggest to make more clear the answer to question 1?